# Is there any way to connect blender to processing?

Tags: python, scripting, external-applications

I would like to produce [processing](https://processing.org/) style effects in blender or other traditional applications, either 2d or 3d. I have been looking for ways to connect the language to blender through blender's internal python interpreter. So far I have found nothing. I even looked for ways to call jython libraries within blender, as processing.py is a jython wrapper around the java original, and the closest I have found was some information on blender java. I would much rather use an up to date more feature rich version of blender than a java port. Does any one know of a way to call jython from with in Cpython that would be compatible with blender or a java or javascript to python method that would work? Even the location of a pure python script that works like processing would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the question is a little off topic for the blender.stackexchange

There is [python-osc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-osc) for talking over OSC between Blender and any OSC supporting program (Processing comes with an OSC library). You could make your own bindings.

Comment: Thank you I will look into that. I am just curious though how well OSC handles visual media since it was designed for sound. I guess I will inquire about that over at python-osc.

Comment: @yehochanan consider the osc 'stream' more as a way to send higher level instructions from one program to another. Just like OSC isn't used to send samples, but you might send a filepath of a new sample to load - You might send condensed draw commands over OSC or again a filepath so Processing can read instructions from disk. (I/O is pretty fast these days)